# Cannot restore Amazon RDS SQL Server database to given point-in-time using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, restore, amazon-rds

I'm trying to restore one of my Amazon DRS SQL Server databases. Using SQL Server Management Studio, I can correct to my DRS instance using the master account I created when creating the database instance. When I start restoring a given database I'm able to see all full backups and transaction logs, but it gives me this error message when trying to restore

> *Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)*
>
> *An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)*
>
> *The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_fileexist', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)*

I can restore a full database instance from AWS management console, but that is not what I want. I want to be able to restore a given database to a specific point-in-time and not restoring a whole new database instance. Also looks there isn't much information on how to restore to a specific point-in-time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would try scripting out the operation instead of running whatever Management Studio is doing "for" you. You shouldn't need to use `xp_fileexist` (assuming you can validate that the files actually exist in the place the script says). Using 2012 SSMS, I am restoring to a point in time that does not coincide directly with a log backup:

[image]

The resulting script in my case was:

```
BACKUP LOG ... WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, NORECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD
RESTORE LOG ... WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD
...
RESTORE LOG ... FROM DISK = [...path from line 1...] WITH NOUNLOAD, STOPAT = <time>
```

Comment: It is not even allowing me to generate the script. same message. My DB is on Amazon RDS and the account I use (which is the admin account create when did the db set up) seems not having the right to read backup files on AWS disks.

Comment: Then I suspect you will need to contact AWS support directly.